# How to create db schema to allow table inheritence with EF

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I am trying to layout a database with multiple tables of a similar type.  Consider a simplified veterinarian system.  I have the following tables:

- Dogs
- Cats
- Birds
- Owners

My one constraint is that each Owner can have exactly 1 pet.  I would like to keep referential integrity, but do not want to have my Owners table have three columns dedicated to foreign keys (seeing as I may need to add further pet species at some point).

Furthermore, when working with Entity Framework, I would like to have the entities setup to link as simple as Owner.Pet and have the underlying mechanisms handle deciding which table it needs to pull from.

I have come up with a way to do the second portion, but it is messy, at best.  Has anyone tried something like this and had good luck coming up with a somewhat elegant solution?

Comment: There is ample documentation on mapping inheritance. Didn't you find anything that helped you?

Comment: What you describe most probably fit to TPT inheritance but you will have one additional table called Pet which will be parent for Dogs, Cats and Birds.

Comment: I did attempt to create an effective Pet table, it included an ID, the name, and the sex of the pet.  Then I had each of the"child" tables use the same ID from the Pet table (i.e. each had a PetID, instead of a DogID, CatID, or BirdID).  However, I could not get EF to do what I wanted (though maybe it was not meant to)

Comment: GetArnold - I have poured through much documentation, but I am either a little too green to see that it is telling me I can't do what I want, or I think I need to find an article/individual who will tell me I can't do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

For TPT inheritance, you'd make one table called `Pet` with an ID PK.

You'd then make a second table called `Cat` with a PK which is *both* a PK and a FK to `Pet`.

Having done this, you can now [create a TPT model using these steps](http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-table-per-type-inheritance/).